# Javascript : "event is sent to an element" -

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm inexperienced with javascript/jquery. I was reading the docs for http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/ where it states:

> The mouseover event is sent to an element when the mouse pointer enters the element. Any HTML element can receive this event.

1) What sends the event to the element ?
2) Is the event 'stored' in the element? I'm imagining that each HTML element in the DOM is treated as an object and the presence or absence of the event is a property of the object.

Answer (score 1):

The browser itself generates the event, which is a special object implementing the `Event` interface and it is passed to the handler function as an argument. The event is not stored in the element, it is created by the engine.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right rack, [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/) should help you better understand Javascript and how browsers operate. It is the documentation for the DOM Level 2. This is when functionality to allow scripts and other programs to dynamically access and update various sections of content and structure of the DOM was added. It includes a list of the various interfaces that were introduced.

HTML elements on their own implement an interface called the [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), which is the base interface for HTML elements, either directly or indirectly through an interface that inherits it.

Elements themselves are interfaces that represent an object within the document. The Element interface lays out various properties that are common for numerous kinds of elements.

There are a couple of different interfaces within the web platform. 
It's always a plus to look up these various interfaces and learn how they interact. The [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) is a great starting place.